# Is there any good way to shorten this code?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to shorten this code? I cant think of anything that will work other than maybe using a loop.

```
function blackOut() {
'use strict';
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(95%)', 'filter': 'brightness(95%)'}); }, 100);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(90%)', 'filter': 'brightness(90%)'}); }, 200);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(85%)', 'filter': 'brightness(85%)'}); }, 300);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(80%)', 'filter': 'brightness(80%)'}); }, 400);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(75%)', 'filter': 'brightness(75%)'}); }, 500);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(70%)', 'filter': 'brightness(70%)'}); }, 600);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(65%)', 'filter': 'brightness(65%)'}); }, 700);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(60%)', 'filter': 'brightness(60%)'}); }, 800);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(55%)', 'filter': 'brightness(55%)'}); }, 900);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(50%)', 'filter': 'brightness(50%)'}); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(45%)', 'filter': 'brightness(45%)'}); }, 1100);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(40%)', 'filter': 'brightness(40%)'}); }, 1200);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(35%)', 'filter': 'brightness(35%)'}); }, 1300);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(30%)', 'filter': 'brightness(30%)'}); }, 1400);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(25%)', 'filter': 'brightness(25%)'}); }, 1500);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(20%)', 'filter': 'brightness(20%)'}); }, 1600);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(15%)', 'filter': 'brightness(15%)'}); }, 1700);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(10%)', 'filter': 'brightness(10%)'}); }, 1800);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(5%)', 'filter': 'brightness(5%)'}); }, 1900);
setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(0%)', 'filter': 'brightness(0%)'}); }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Do a loop and increase the values?

Comment: @Vucko You mean decrease. It should go down from 95% to 0%.

Comment: `$("body")` suggest you're already using a framework. Does that framework provide animagion features?

Comment: why not a setInterval that runs until you got to 0

Comment: I have a feeling you can do it with CSS3 animations.

Comment: jQuery has an [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function but using CSS3 animations is much better.

Comment: For review requests on working code, consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9):

You should be using a CSS animation triggered by a class change.

CSS :

```
body {
  -webkit-filter : brightness(100%);
  filter : brightness(100%);
}
body.shadowed {
  -webkit-filter : brightness(0%);
  filter : brightness(0%);
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

jquery :

```
$("body").addClass("shadowed");
```

Comment: The code seemed like it should work but it is not working on my browser even though i more or less copied the entire thing.


Edit: going to try to run it without other random things on my webpage. will update

Comment: Is this supposed to be how it looks like or did I mess something up? https://jsfiddle.net/f0a69ync/

Comment: @Switch turns out it's not working on my side either. I'm in the process of checking what's wrong, I hope to have an answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Switchok I figured an easy workaround : don't provide the targeted property to the transition and let it work it out. Updated my answer.

Comment: here's your modified fiddle that correctly shows the progressive shadowing : https://jsfiddle.net/f0a69ync/2/

Comment: `-webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 2s;   transition: filter 2s;` if you don't want to transition any animatable property of the document.

Comment: @Kaiido that's what I had before, and it turns out it didn't work. You can test that on [Switch's first fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0a69ync/) : just remove the transition's target property and it starts working. Maybe it has something to do with the fact it's a meta-property? I couldn't find anything more closely related to brightness.

Comment: @Aaron, right I only tested on FF where it odes work. It actually has to do with chrome not supporting `-webkit-transition` anymore, so it should be `transition: filter 2s -webkit-filter 2s;` just as in @putvande's answer below

Comment: @Kaiido I just tried it on chrome and it didn't work either (it goes from 100% to 0% brightness instantly). Thanks for trying though !

Comment: @Kaiido ok so with only the -webkit-filter defined, it works under chrome. but as soon as I define a standard filter, it takes precedence over the -webkit-filter and is applied instantly, as if it wasn't recognized as a transitable property...

Comment: @Switch you're very welcome, that was more interesting that I would have originally thought with the -webkit quirks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `transition`:

```
body {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
    filter: brightness(100%);
    transition: -webkit-filter 2s, filter 2s;
}

body.blackout {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0%);
    filter: brightness(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** with `opacity` attribute, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$("h1").animate({
  opacity: 0
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: For the most part it does not have the effect i want it to have(gradually gets dark. your code makes it instantly turn black) and i'm also not sure about this: http://puu.sh/mJ0kw/48d79b3912.png

Comment: Try now @Switch, the problem in your screenshot should disappear if we throw the fonction outside the loop and pass just a reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bright = 95;
var time=100;
for(var i = 0; i<10;i++){

    setTimeout(function () { $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness('+bright+'%)', 'filter': 'brightness('+bright+'%)'}); }, time);

    time+=100;
    bright-=5;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you can do it with CSS animations. But to do it the way you are with timeouts, use an interval with a counter and remove it when you hit zero.

```js
function blackOut() {
  var step = 100,
    interval = window.setInterval(change, 100);

  function change() {
    step -= 5;
    $("body").css({
      '-webkit-filter': 'brightness(' + step + '%)',
      'filter': 'brightness(' + step + '%)'
    });
    if (step === 0) window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

$("button").on("click", blackOut);
```

```css
body * {
  background-color: #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test</h2>
<div>Test</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `setInterval` function:

```
(​function() {
    var runs = 20,
        degree = 95;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        $("body").css({'-webkit-filter': 'brightness(' + degree + '%)', 'filter': 'brightness(' + degree + '%)'});
        degree -= 5;                        
        --runs;
        if (runs == 0) {
             clearInterval(i);
        }    
    }, 100);
}());​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should use keyframes with css, (i writed this example with stylus)

```
body 
    animation: brightness 2s linear infinite


@keyframes brightness 
    0% 
         filter: brightness 0%
    50%
         filter: brightness 50%
    100%
         filter: brightness 100%
```